# Navigate the back button to another activity Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

So im trying to make the back button navigate from one activity at another (from lets say I want activity1, activity2, activity3 to navigate to the mainActivity (level selection)) since at the moment it only navigates back to itself then closes the application like so
[image]

i tried adding the "NoHistory =true" to 
 `[Activity(Label = "firstQ", NoHistory =true)]` 
 but that didnt do anything at all, any idea on what could fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NoHistory=true` attribute flag is actually used for the "Up" button on the action bar. See here for [more](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) information.

What you are looking to do is to override the back button behaviour. What you could do here is something like

Activitiy1:

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
    StartActivity(intent);

    //base.OnBackPressed(); -> DO NOT CALL THIS LINE OR WILL NAVIGATE BACK
}
```

This method is fired as soon as the back button is pressed on the foreground activity. By commenting out (or not calling) `base.OnBackPressed();` will stop the activity from going back and you can start your new activity ie `MainActivity`.

Now in the case your hierarchy is actually different than you say where `MainActivity` is essentially your `root` Activity and you are starting others in sequence where pressing the back button returns you to the Main activity you can take a similar approach but will require some additional flags. For this instance you are probably interested in the [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) or in Xamarin Terms [`ActivityFlags.ClearTop`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Content.ActivityFlags.ClearTop/)

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the
>   current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that
>   activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and
>   this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a
>   new Intent.
>
> For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D.
>   If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the
>   component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive
>   the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.

Now the implementation is almost identical with the added intent flags.

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
    StartActivity(intent);
    //base.OnBackPressed(); -> DO NOT CALL THIS LINE OR WILL NAVIGATE BACK
}
```

Comment: Thank you very well explained answer! Made me understand how it works!

Comment: I always get these errors though might be because im very tierd but am I placing it in the wrong section of the code? I tried moving it around with no positive outcome. https://i.gyazo.com/389df3cb70f7069e7b5ca11df926e0bc.png

Comment: Looks like a copy & paste issue to me. Make sure that this is withing the class declaration.